# Ruby or Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to build a browser based remote SSH using Ruby. I am not sure whether to use Ruby or Ruby on Rails.

There won’t be any database involved. I just want to display the output of my commands neatly on the browser. Can this be achieved using Ruby alone or is it better to use Ruby on Rails?

More Info:
Basically, I will have an HTML page which will POST the SSH command. This command will be executed on the remote machine and then the result will be returned. It will be something like this: Net::SSH.start( HOST, USER, :password => PASS ) do|ssh| result = ssh.exec!('ls') puts result I don't know how to POST the command from HTML to ruby code. I also don't know how to return "result" back to the HTML page. I want to print what is present in 'result' on the HTML page.

Comment: Have you considered http://www.sinatrarb.com/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby on Rails is a web framework that has been written in the Ruby programming language. If you don't take the time to learn the Ruby syntax, you will struggle with Rails. Not saying you must become an expert in all things Ruby, but you should at a minimum get comfortable with the basic object classes (arrays, strings, hashes, etc) and their corresponding methods. If you are just getting started, I would urge you to check out Chris Pine's site - http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/ which covers the basics of the Ruby programming language, then you can start reading through the Rails Guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html to learn more about the framework.

This site will help you out the most: http://www.sinatrarb.com/

I really think that `sinatra` will be most beneficial for you. You don't need the extra stuff that Rails does.

Comment: erb is a templating system that embeds Ruby into a text document. is this what you want?

Comment: Basically, I will have an HTML page which will POST the SSH command. This command will be executed on the remote machine and then the result will be returned. It will be something like this:
 Net::SSH.start( HOST, USER, :password => PASS ) do|ssh|
 result = ssh.exec!('ls')
 puts result
I don't know how to POST the command from HTML to ruby code. I also don't know how to return "result" back to the HTML page. I want to print what is present in 'result' on the HTML page.

Comment: I can't help you there because I don't have experience with erb. But from your logic it does seem that you will be able to do so. Good luck!

Comment: Oh I think now I understand the purpose of ERB. In my case, it can generate the final HTML with the contents of "result". I can then pass that HTML to the user. Is that correct?

Comment: Again, I am no expert with ERB. But from what I heard about it, I think it might be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) if you don't need all of the infrastructure of Rails. It'll get all your code into the browser without all the extra STUFF that Rails gives you, that you likely won't make use of.